# How to Prioritize OR condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table structure something like this

```
+---+----------+-----------+--------------+
| id| customer | Address   | Address_type |
+---+----------+-----------+--------------+
|1  | 1        | Address 1 | 2            |
|2  | 2        | Address 2 | 2            |
|3  | 1        | Address 3 | 1            |
+---+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

There are two Address_types in Database. 
I have to select Address based on following conditions

1. If Address for costumer of Address_type = 1 is present then display that address.
2. If Address_type = 1 is not present and Address_type = 2 is present then display Address_type = 2 Address for that customer.
3. If both are present for that customer then display only Address where Address_type = 1

I have tried this by OR condition but it displays record whichever is first in Database so there is way in mysql query to achieve this with only one query? i.e. something like giving priority in OR condition to fetch only Address_type = 1 record when both Address_types(1 and 2) are present in Database?

Comment: Can you please add a sample output in a tabular format? It is not clear if you want to fetch only the matching rows, if you're trying to group, or if you really want one column with addresses, as you said in your question.

Comment: For now I am fetching only one row by customer Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option: get the minimum `Address_Type` for each customer, then join to that:

```
SELECT
  id,
  customer,
  Address,
  Address_Type
FROM custs
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT customer, MIN(Address_Type) AS MinType
  FROM custs
  GROUP BY customer
) AddType ON custs.Address_Type = AddType.MinType
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
SELECT 
  yt1.*
FROM 
  your_table yt1 
  LEFT JOIN your_table yt2 ON ( yt2.customer = yt1.customer AND yt2.address_type < yt1.address_type )
WHERE 
  yt2.id IS NULL
```

Outputs:

```
| ID | CUSTOMER |   ADDRESS | ADDRESS_TYPE |
-----|----------|-----------|--------------|
|  1 |        1 | Address 1 |            2 |
|  2 |        3 | Address 2 |            2 |
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1754/2)

Comment: Just thought in the same thing. I thought I was the only one out there solving greatest-n-per-group issues with the left join... everybody uses the group by solution... BTW, change `<` for `>`

Comment: @MostyMostacho Yes, thanks for catching it, updated and Glad :)

Comment: Thanks for giving helpful answer this is also a better answer for my question

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  customer,
  COALESCE(
    MAX(CASE WHEN Address_type=1 THEN Address END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN Address_type=2 THEN Address END)
  )
FROM
  tableName
GROUP BY
  customer
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76a82/2).

Comment: @MostyMostacho yes you're right tnx... it is not clear from the question if the id is needed, or if it's fine to return just the address...

Comment: Cool never knew about `COALESCE`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, customer, 
       IF(address_type=1, address, IF(address_type=2, address, null))
                  as address 
FROM customer_table
GROUP BY customer;
```

What this does is that is address type is one, it uses that address, if two, then address 2, else nothing.

Comment: Be careful with the grouping... what ID are you going to get for same customers?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to fetch not only address but all row for that address_type.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an ORDER BY Address_type ASC, this will ensure that any records with a value of 1 for address_type appear first. I couldn't tell you efficiency of sorting versus other methods, but in my opinion ORDER BY is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

No need for or as long as you only need the address for one customer:

```
SELECT Address FROM table WHERE customer=:customerid ORDER BY Address_type ASC LIMIT 1
```

This will order all addresses by type, starting with 1 and returning only one address, If type 1 is not available type 2 will be returned.